# Kafka Stream Co-Partition on Stream / Table Join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I read [this doc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#join-co-partitioning-requirements) where it said stream / table join must have same partitions number on both side.
But I have this topics and partitions, and the code still works, no exception thrown.

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --partitions 5 --replication-factor 1 --topic t-left
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1 --topic t-right --config "cleanup.policy=compact"
```

So the left (stream) has 5 partitions, and the right (table) has 2 partitions only.

From [the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#join-co-partitioning-requirements), I thought some error will happen in this code. I get `Invalid topology` when trying to joins stream / stream with different partitions count, so I thought will have same `Invalid topology` error, which is not.

```
        var leftStream = builder.stream("t-left");
        var rightTable = builder.table("t-right");

        // join
        var joinStream = rightStream.join(leftTable, this::joiner,
                Joined.with(stringSerde, stringSerde, stringSerde));

        joinStream.to("t-join", Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
```

And the join also happened at `t-join`.

How can this happened?

Comment: Please check all of the topics that are created by Kafka Streams. You can update the description with this list. You may find a repartition topic created automatically. In that case, Kafka Streams is creating a repartition topic internally so the join can happen.

Comment: If there is no key-changing operation, no repartition topic should be created and you should indeed get an error... If you don't get an error, the join result should be incorrect. Can you verify/confirm?